# Electret Microphone Pre-Amplifier capacitor

Tags: operational-amplifier, capacitor, amplifier, battery-operated, microphone

I'm building a preamp for an electret microphone, it's fairly similar to the pic below but values are a bit different. I'm wondering about the output cap, can it be increased without boundaries without any ill effect? In this case a 100uF tantalum cap, to have a margin for unknown impedance so that the cutoff frequency is well below 20Hz.

Best regards,
Matt

[image]

Comment: You will likely want to add a parallel capacitor from opamp output to its (-) input. And that needs to be *designed*. You probably will want to do a noise gain analysis of the system, as well. The electret is a really tiny capacitance that's doing the driving and there's not much charge to it. You can't just throw things at an elecret and expect a low noise result. (But they do still work, just sometimes annoyingly poorly at times if no effort goes into it.)

Comment: Using an inverting amp is not a good idea, much better to use a non-inverting amp with its high input impedance. That inverting amp has an input impedance of 1k Ohms which acts in conjunction with the 10k Ohms output impedance of the microphone biasing resistor to give a 10 fold drop in signal amplitude (-20dB). Maximum overall gain is then 1000 * 0.1 =100 which is too low for a microphone pre-amp. The last mic pre-amp I designed I used a non-inverting amp followed by an inverting amp (gain controlling pot inserted between them) and then the overall gain is the product of the three stages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The limiting factor would eventually be that the startup time from power-on could be significant, especially if driving into a high impedance.  I’d also caution against using a tantalum capacitor connected directly to a plug - tants don’t like any kind of reverse voltage and you have no control over what the preamp is going to be connected to; an input that provides phantom power, for example, could result in a firework display.  Also, LM358s have awful crossover distortion, I hope you’re going to use something a little more 21st century.

Comment: `Thanks, I have two options, AD823 or OPA357, would you recommend one over the other?

Comment: @Ma Sa - I haven’t used either of those devices but both look ok.

Answer (score 3):

In round numbers - yes.

The output cap and the input impedance of whatever is downline form a single-pole high-pass filter.  To reduce low-frequency phase shifts, that corner freq should be at least one octave below the lowest frequency of interest.

Note that the 358 has a relatively low gain-bandwidth product.  At higher audio frequencies such as 10 kHz, its open loop gain is only around 35 dB.  With P1 at 100K, the feedback loop will not close at high freqs, increasing output noise and distortion.

As an experimental device, the 358 is low cost and nearly indestructible.  However, it has relatively high input stage noise and harmonic distortion, output stage crossover distortion, and as above, low gain.  For better performance, consider something in the TI TL07x series.

Comment: I commented above that either AD823 or OPA357 will be used, also the pot will likely be 500k or 1M with a 10p feedback cap.